# Functional equation to determine $f(-1)$

Tags: analysis, functions

> There's a function $f$ satisfying:

$$f\left(\frac{1}{1−x}\right)+2\cdot f\left(\frac{x−1}{x}\right)=3x$$

> Find the value of $f(−1)$.

I have no idea how to solve this one. If anyone could help me to understand it, I would be grateful.

Comment: It would improve your Question to sketch some details of what you tried to solve this problem yourself.  It seems clear that you need to investigate what values of $x$ will introduce terms in the equation involving $f(-1)$.  Showing you've made an effort will help Readers respond in ways that match your level of study and interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let $x=2$, so $$f(-1)+2f(\frac{1}{2})=6$$

Similarly, let $x=-1$, $$f(\frac{1}{2})+2f(2)=-3$$

and let $x=\frac{1}{2}$, $$f(2)+2f(-1)=\frac{3}{2}$$

Solve this problem becomes solving the three simultaneous equations.

Answer (score 4):

Plug in $x=2$. Then you obtain $f(-1)+2f(1/2)=6$. On the other hand, for $x=-1$, you obtain $f(1/2)+2f(2)=-3$. For $x=1/2$, you get $f(2)+2f(-1)=3/2$. To sum up, $$f(-1)+2f(1/2)= 6\\ f(1/2)+2f(2)=-3 \\ f(2)+2f(-1)=3/2$$
Now take the values $f(-1),f(1/2),f(2)$ as unknowns and solve the linear system of equations.

Comment: Thank you very much! ❤️

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach in these types of questions is just to fiddle around a bit. So, let's see how we can find $f(-1)$. To get this value, we have two options: choose an $x$ such that $1/(1-x)=-1$ or $(x-1)/x=-1$. For the first option, we get $x=2$ and the second option we get $x=1/2$. Now, let's fill this in and we get for $x=2$:
$$ f(-1) + 2\cdot f(1/2) = 6 $$
and for $x=1/2$
$$ f(2) + 2\cdot f(-1) = 3/2. $$
We don't know $f(1/2)$ and $f(2)$. So, let's see what we can say about those. For $f(2)$, we use the value of $x=-1$ to get
$$ f(1/2) + 2\cdot f(2) = -3. $$
This is an incredibly nice result since now we have $3$ unknowns and three equations which we should be able to solve using linear algebra. In this case you get $f(-1)=2$, $f(1/2)=2$ and $f(2)=-5/2$.

Answer (score 0):

set $x = -1$ into to the formula of $f$:

$$f\left(\frac{1}{1−x}\right)+2\cdot f\left(\frac{x−1}{x}\right)=3x $$

you'll have for $x = -1$:

$$f\left(\frac{1}{1−(-1)}\right)+2\cdot f\left(\frac{(-1)−1}{(-1)}\right)=-3$$

$$ = f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+2\cdot f\left(2\right)=-3$$

*Notice that the denominator of is different then $0$*

and for $x = \frac{1}{2}$:

$$f\left(2\right)+2\cdot f\left(-1\right)=1.5 $$
 for $x=2$:

$$f(-1)+2\cdot f\left(\frac{1}{2} \right)= 6 $$

Then:

$f(-1) = 6 - 2f\left(\frac{1}{2} \right) = \frac{-f(2)}{2} + \frac{3}{4}$ ,
 as $ \ -2f\left(\frac{1}{2} \right) = 4f(2) + 6 $

Therefore $f(2) = -2.5 \ \Longrightarrow \ f(-1) = \frac{-2.5}{-2} + \frac{3}{4} = 2$

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $1-\frac{1}{x}$ instead of $x$.

We obtain:
$$f\left(\frac{1}{1-1+\frac{1}{x}}\right)+2f\left(1-\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{x}}\right)=3\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ or
$$f(x)+2f\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)=3\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right).$$
Now, substitute $1-\frac{1}{x}$ instead of $x$ in the last equation.

We obtain:
$$f\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)+2f\left(\frac{1}{1-1+\frac{1}{x}}\right)=3\left(1-\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{x}}\right)$$ or
$$f\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)+2f(x)=\frac{3}{1-x}.$$
Id est,
$$f(x)=3\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)-2f\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)=\frac{3(x-1)}{x}-2\left(3x-2f\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)=$$
$$=\frac{3(x-1)}{x}-2\left(3x-2\left(\frac{3}{1-x}-2f(x)\right)\right),$$
which gives
$$9f(x)=\frac{3(x-1)}{x}-6x+\frac{12}{1-x}$$ or
$$f(x)=\frac{x-1}{3x}-\frac{2x}{3}+\frac{4}{3(1-x)}$$ and $$f(-1)=\frac{2}{3}+\frac{2}{3}+\frac{2}{3}=2.$$